# How to properly install Apache, MySQL, and PHP on Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, mysql, php

I have followed a guide on how to install Apache, MySQL, and PHP on my laptop running Linux (Ubuntu 10.4) It appears I have it installed correctly but when I am not sure. I followed this guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

When I go to localhost I in fact see the Apache info page that confirms it installed. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhfxR.png

I ran and installed the following in this order:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf (I added index.php to the beginning)
```

Lastly, and where my issues currently is, I ran:

```
sudo nano /var/www/info.php
```

and made a simple php file to give me the phpinfo

When I navigate to localhost/info.php in browser I get an error on the page

Not found: The requested URL /info.php was not found on this server.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please see this guide - http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/05/lamp-server-installation-configuration.html

Comment: Please check the apache error log. It is probably looking for info.php at some other location. The error log will tell you where the URL is looking for this page.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu. That 10.4 is end-of-life in 6 months